# Javascript URL depth (level)

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get url depth (level) with Javascript?

If I have this url:
www.website.com/site/product/category/item -> depth=4
www.website.com/site/product/category -> depth=3

Comment: Sure, it can be easily done. What have you tried?

Comment: Have you considered how you would want to handle URL slugs/fragments that also contain slashes? For example: `www.navitua.com/users?role=admin/root`

Answer (score 6):

I would use a regex to determine how many matches there are for a slash followed by one or more characters.

```
var url = "www.website.com/site/product/category/item";
url.match(/\/.+?/g).length; // returns 4
```

**Edit:** Added a few checks against query strings and double slashes. (credit to user Lix for sparking the idea)

```
var url = "www.website.com/site/product/category/item?url=/query/string/path";
url.split(/[?#]/).shift().match(/\/[^/]+?/g).length;
```

Comment: My knee jerk reaction was to use `split` as mentioned by other answers but if you're only after the **number of slashes** then this approach is much better.

Comment: @Lix split is a good approach especially if you're accounting for slashes in query strings or hashes as you mentioned in your other comment.  The only thing to watch out for with that approach is the need to trim the string of trailing slashes.  `split` might be the better approach for OP.

Answer (score 4):

simply split it by "/" and check the length of returning array

```js
    var url = "www.website.com/site/product/category/item";
    alert("depth is " + (url.split("/").length - 1));
    url = "www.website.com/site/product/category"
    alert("depth is " + (url.split("/").length - 1));
```