# How can you see how many paths a URL has?

Tags: javascript, url

I would like to figure out how you can figure out how many paths are in a URL. For instance, example.com/example/hello/ would return 2, and example.com/example would return 1, and example.com/example/anotherexample/hello would return 3. How can I do this in Javascript and have it work either if the URL ends in / or does not?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - Get Portion of URL Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path)

Comment: Then just split the pathname on / and filter out any empty values.

Comment: would you mind accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we can approach this question by first thinking about what a path is. Fundamentally, a path is a way to access a resource, and you usually get there via folders. We can get the `pathname` of a location by using

```
window.location.pathname
```

in the case of our current url, it will return

```
/questions/62353998/how-can-you-see-how-many-paths-a-url-has
```

or

```
/questions/62353998/how-can-you-see-how-many-paths-a-url-has/
```

So, we can get the exact answer by trimming off "/" paths (which are empty) and counting them up. Using javascript, we can get this number by doing

```
window.location.pathname.split("/").filter(a => a.length > 0).length
```

Breaking it down, we're

1. getting the pathname (`window.location.pathname`)
2. splitting the path into the directories we've traveled to get there (`.split("/")`)
3. filtering out empty paths `""` (`.filter(a => a.length > 0)`)

generally of course, you can also do some complex regex

```
window.location.href.split(/[?#]/).shift().match(/\/[^/]+?/g).length
```

(last code snippet lifted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36983925/4166655)

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! Would you mind accepting my answer :P